# Filming locations for La Jetée?

Tags: real-location, la-jetee

What were the shooting locations for Chris Marker's [La Jetée](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056119/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1962)? In particular, where did they film the museum scene and the underground bunkers?

(For context: I have the chance to go to Paris and want to visit those locations if possible.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056119/locations);

- The museum scene was filmed at the *[Galerie De Paléontologie Et D'Anatomie Comparée Du Muséum National D'Histoire Naturelle](https://www.mnhn.fr/fr/galerie-de-paleontologie-et-d-anatomie-comparee)* (The Gallery of Paleontology and Comparative Anatomy at the French National Museum of Natural History).
- The eponymous jetté is found at [*Orly Airport*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orly_Airport)

The bunkers are identified [here](https://www.centrepompidou-metz.fr/en/la-jet-e-larm-e-des-douze-singes);

- The bunkers were part of the [*Catacombes de Paris*](https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/catacombes-de-paris) beneath the Palais de Chaillot

Comment: I believe the park to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parc_Montsouris, but I've not been able to positively identify the markers